# Retrive only part of a subdocument in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have some data that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : "5227aa5d9881d31cd3aa0e78",
"Message" : "This is a message 5:47 PM",
"IssuedAt" : ISODate("2013-09-04T21:47:09.932Z"),
"Users" : [
    {
        "_id" : "dhBHuZL9M+hqtKIx14iu",
        "IsRead" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : "SOMSOMOMODJFJDFKJKDJF",
        "IsRead" : false
    }
]
}
```

and I was hoping retrieve the following about one user:

```
{
  "_id" : "5227aa5d9881d31cd3aa0e78",
  "Message" : "This is a message 5:47 PM",
  "IssuedAt" : ISODate("2013-09-04T21:47:09.932Z"),
  "IsRead" : false
}
```

I tried this but it will only return the record with the whole subdocument:

```
db.collection.find({"Users": {$elemMatch: {"_id": 'dhBHuZL9M+hqtKIx14iu'}}}, {"Message": 1, "Users.$.IsRead": 1}).pretty()
```

Is there a way to get what I am looking for without using aggregate?

Comment: Sorry, you either get to tell projection which subelement you want returned or which fields in the subelements you want- no way to do both right now.

Comment: whats the reason behind not using `aggregate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current requirement , i think you have to redesign your schema . Schema has to be more efficient for your query. May be Schema for the current requirement will be to have **User** Collection

```
                 { 
                  "_id": "dhBHuZL9M+hqtKIx14iu" ,
                   "Name" : "Test",
                    "ReadMessages" [{}],
                    "UnReadMessage" [{}]
                 }
```

Now for any users you can get the read messages and unread message very easy . One update statement you have to fire to move the message from UnRead to read. But it will happen once and rest read will be very fast. I know it will not solve your problem but may help you wish to change the schema.